# Covariance of binomial variables

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

I have three events that can be modeled by the binomial distribution, X = binom(4, 0.3), Y = binom(4, 0.4), and Z = binom(4,0.3). Im confused how to find the covariance between them; ie: Cov(X,Y), Cov(X,Z). I need this information to prove whether the events are independent.
I also found the joint distribution of the three to be a multinomial distribution. Is that correct?

Comment: I think you must have been given a multinomial distribution to start with.  Can you write down the probabilities for each of the 15 (X,Y,Z) possibilities, e.g. Pr(X=0,Y=1,Z=3) = 0.0432?  Then you can calculate things like E(X) and E(XY); and use those to calculate e.g. Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y).

Comment: I am supposed to find the joint distribution for the three events and i found that the joint distribution should be a multinomial one. Would that be correct?

Comment: Assuming that X, Y and Z are mutually exclusive and cover all possibilities, yes, multinomial is the right joint distribution.

Comment: Yes, that would be the case. I think i figured it out! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The terminology is wrong X, Y and Z are random variables. The covariance structure cannot be determined without more information such as what @Creosote suggests.